# dropdown display text as variation of value asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have a dropdown list that is programatically filled with the dates of the last 60 days (current + 59 prior). What I would like to do is make it so the value of the dropdown is formatted as yyyy-MM-dd and the dropdown text is displayed to the user as eg: Sat, 23 Feb 2017 (format: "ddd, dd-MM-yyyy").

I can get them both the same, but can't figure out how to create the variation.

Am I approaching this the right way? Any pointers you can give would be amazing!

My code to populate the dropdown in c# is:

```
    List<ListItem> dateItems = new List<ListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        dateItems.Add(new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToString(format: "ddd, dd-MM-yyyy")));
    }
    recDate.DataSource = dateItems;
    recDate.DataBind();

    recDate.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

and currently it is showing in the rendered HTML as:

```
<option value="Mon, 18-09-2017">Mon, 18-09-2017</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the missing piece of the puzzle was:

```
recordDate.DataValueField = "Value";
recordDate.DataTextField = "Text";
recordDate.DataSource = dateItems;
recordDate.DataBind();
```

WIN! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
List<ListItem> dateItems = new List<ListItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i);
    dateItems.Add(new ListItem(date.ToString("ddd, dd-MM-yyyy"), date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
}
recDate.DataSource = dateItems;
recDate.DataBind();

recDate.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Camilo! I understand the constructor you laid out, but for some reason it seems to just be ignoring the part after the comma. Any ideas at all? :-S

Comment: @cloudseeker can you add a screenshot/error message of what you mean by "ignoring the part after the comma"?

Comment: It is not throwing an error, it is just disregarding the subsequent request for the value format. With the code the way it stands, it is just showing as eg: `<option value="Fri, 15-09-2017">Fri, 15-09-2017</option>` so it is ignoring the **date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))** but not sure why.